# Php: need returned variable to be available to all other functions in a class

Tags: php

I have this model class that has several functions in it. I need to get the variable $new_route after its been set by the if statements to be available to all the other functions. I included them initially at the top of the class, not in a function, but the if statements kill that. I can include those lines of code in every function and it works the way I want, but I know that way sucks. I wrapped the code in a function getRoute() but how do I execute the function inside the class automatically so that the variables are available for all the other functions?

```
  public function getRoute() {
                 $find_route = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
             $get_route = explode('&',$find_route);
            $set_route = explode('/',$get_route[0]);
             $new_route = $set_route[1];    
                if ($new_route == 'memberships'){
                    $new_route = "MEMBER";  
                }elseif ($new_route == 'donations'){
                    $new_route = "DONATE";
                }elseif ($new_route == 'tickets'){
                    $new_route = "TICKET";
                }elseif ($new_route == 'items'){
                    $new_route = "ITEM";
                }elseif ($new_route == 'peer'){
                    $new_route = "PEER";
                }elseif ($new_route == 'recurring'){
                    $new_route = "RECURRING";
                }
            return $new_route;
            }
```

Comment: Make it a class-level variable?  Return the value from the function and use the returned value?  It's not clear what you *should* be doing without seeing where the value needs to be used.  But there are a few different ways to pass values around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the function you will have to either use another file e.g. `run.php` or you can run the function at the bottom of your class so for example:

```
class your_class {
public function getRoute() {
                 $find_route = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
             $get_route = explode('&',$find_route);
            $set_route = explode('/',$get_route[0]);
             $new_route = $set_route[1];    
                if ($new_route == 'memberships'){
                    $new_route = "MEMBER";  
                }elseif ($new_route == 'donations'){
                    $new_route = "DONATE";
                }elseif ($new_route == 'tickets'){
                    $new_route = "TICKET";
                }elseif ($new_route == 'items'){
                    $new_route = "ITEM";
                }elseif ($new_route == 'peer'){
                    $new_route = "PEER";
                }elseif ($new_route == 'recurring'){
                    $new_route = "RECURRING";
                }
            return $new_route;
      }   
}
$this->getRoute();
```

Then the output should be the correct output :)

However I would advise you use another file which has the class required and used e.g.

```
<?php
   require_once('class.php');
   $class = new class();
   $getRoute = $class->getRoute();
   print_r($getRoute); // For testing the code
?>
```